# Creating multiple request from HOC in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

i wanted to create multiple request from hoc,where i was able to create hoc for single request(redux action which call api),please check the code for single request

i have created hoc for reducing repeated code in every component,like on `componentdidmount` calling api,managing error,managing loading state but it is only for single request like you can see in intial object in given hoc,so i want a to create hoc which can executes for multiple request(redux action which calls api),i dont know that this solution which is working for single request is properly implemented or not

So,please help me to create hoc which can be resealable for any given scenario

> hoc

```
export const ComponentWithAPIRequest = ({ onMount = null, LoaderRequestID,onUnmount = null }) => (WrappedComponent) => {
return class ComponentWithAPIRequest extends Component {
    state = {
        stateLoader: true // intial Load
    };
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.Request();
    };

    componentWillUnmount() {
        onUnmount !== null ? this.props[onUnmount]() : null;
    }

    Request = () => {
        onMount !== null ? this.props[onMount](LoaderRequestID) : null; // API request
        this.setState({ stateLoader: false });
    };

    render() {
        const { error, isLoading } = this.props; // pass it here somehow.
        const { stateLoader } = this.state;
        const isLoadingFromAPI = this.props.isLoadingRequestIds.indexOf(LoaderRequestID) !== -1 ? true : false;

        if (stateLoader) {
            return (
                <div className="text-center">
                    <CircularProgress />
                </div>
            );
        }
        if (isLoadingFromAPI) {
            return (
                <div className="text-center">
                    <CircularProgress />
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} retry={this.Request} />;
        }
    }
};
};
```

> component

```
export const isContainer = ({ intial, list }) => (WrappedComponent) => {
 const IsContainer = (props) => <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
 return compose(ComponentWithAPIRequest(intial), hasRequestError) 
 (IsContainer);
};



hasRequestError // is error hoc
ComponentWithAPIRequest // is above added hoc



@isContainer({
intial: {
    onMount: 'FirstRequest', // is a redux action which call api,here i want to have multiple request like ['FirstRequest','SecondRequest'] 
    LoaderRequestID: 'FirstRequestLoader', // is an unique id for loader,which then for multiple request be converted to respective request like ['FirstRequestLoader','SecondRequestLoader'] 
    onUnmount: 'ResetLeaderBoardAll' // is a redux action when component unmount
}
 })
class ComponentView extends Component {
render() {
    return (
            <SomeComponent {...this.props}/>
    );
 }
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

   return {
    somestate:state
   };
 };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
 FirstRequest,
 SecondRequest
})(ComponentView);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would update your hoc and pass multiple URLs as parameter to send multiple requests like:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentWithAPIRequest(ComponentView,
    [
       "url1", "url2" ... 
    ]));
```

And pass them back to ComponentView with 'props' or 'props.requestResponses'(single) object. Then I would use them like

```
const url1response = this.props.requestResponses["url1"];
```

In my case, I would store them in ComponentWithAPIRequest's state but you can use redux and get them from mapStateToProps in ComponentView as well.